# why do we say "most days" not most of the days"?

Tags: grammar

I had seen so many examples like this that in contrast with my expectation the "of the" part is omitted my question is why that happens?

> Most people liked that

> Most days

not

> Most of the people

> Most of the days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fairly fruitful exchange between adverbs, pronouns and determiners in English.  It is quite common for a word to change from one class to another by omitting a word or two.

This is the case with "most".  It can shift word class from determiner  "Most people went home."  To a pronoun "Most went home" or "Most of the people went home"

There may be nuanced differences:

> Most people like sweet food.  (a general fact about people)

> Most of the people like sweet food (a fact about a specific group of people)

English does this because there are few word endings that mark the part of speech of a word.  This makes it very easy for a word to change its part of speech, without changing the form of the word.

It is the same with "most days"

> Most days I wake at 7  (a general fact about the days in my life)

> Most of the days I woke at 7 (a fact about a specific group of days, in context "the days" might be "the days that I was at college" or "the days during the summer holidays" for example)